# How do I set this <div> to be at the bottom centre of each page?

Tags: html, css

I want the arrow to be at the bottom centre above my footer on my web page but I don't want to scroll down to see it. I think the issue is the length of the background picture? As a result, this is why I have to scroll down to see the arrow?  Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/lemmin/pen/KaRKBj) of how I wanted it to look like. Here is my [website](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/OWZMpY). Scroll down on my website to see the arrows. Apologies about the structure it's only my second day programming.

**I have to scroll down to see the arrow on the first page which I don't want, I want it to be above footer in the centre.**

Here is the HTML coding.

```
<div id="page"></div>
  <section class="one">

<div class="next"><</div>
  </section>
  <section class="two">

<div class="next"><</div>
  </section>
  <section class="three">

    <div class="next"><</div>
      </section>
      <section class="four">
    <div class="next"><</div>
      </section>
  <section class="one">
    <div></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS.

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
#page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
section {
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
section > div {
  font-family:Georgia,Sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:96px;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
}

.next {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-40px;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  cursor:pointer;
}

.one {
   background-color: #45CCFF;
}
.two {
  background-color: #49E83E;
}
.three {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
}
.four {
  background-color: #E84B30;
```

Kind Regards,

Liam.

Comment: Your code appears to already do exactly what you're asking: https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/7L23wugo/. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @Obsidian AgeI Apologies, I don't think you understand what I mean. I want the arrow to be at the bottom of my web page but I don't want to scroll down to see it. I  think the issue is the length of the background picture? As a result, this is why I have to scroll down to see the arrow?

Comment: Copying your code doesn't seem to give me that problem -- the arrow already *is* already visible for me without scrolling -- https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/uknx5cyc/ (I broke the last fiddle, sorry :P). It has `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`, so it should always *be* at the bottom. Can you please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? An actual code fiddle would help :)

Comment: @Obsidian Age Look at my website though, I have to scroll down to see it on the first page which I don't want.

Comment: I see the problem now, bear with me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your two `.title4` elements occupy space *above* your first `<section>`:

```
<h1 class="title4">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
<h1 class="title4">PORTFOLIO</h1>
<section></section>
```

Your section has a height of 100vh, and is what you want to have all elements contained *within*.

Simply shift those two elements to within your section, and your footer caret will magically appear :)

To shift your caret *up* (so that it doesn't disappear behind your footer), simply adjust the `bottom` value of `.next`:

```
.next {
    bottom: 35px;
}
```

Be aware that shifting the caret up by adjusting its position to bottom will make it higher up the section. It may instead by preferable to adjust the section's height to accommodate the footer externally:

```
section {
  height:calc(100vh - 34px);
}
```

I've created an updated CodePen showcasing this [here](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/apGNRg).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your time. Last question, what's wrong with the JS as the arrows don't work when you click on them?

Comment: You accidentally closed the `#page` DIV before loading the `<section>`s. The JavaScript was looking for `<section>`s that were *children* of `<div id="page">`. I've fixed up my CodePen to correct that :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your background picture size.

Comment: Untrue. A smaller background picture would not solve this problem.